# Proteção ajax e php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, segurança

Usar ajax no meu caso, pode trazer alguma falha de segurança? Se sim, como faço para resolver? 
javascript:

```
$(function() {
    if($('#login_submit').length !== 0) {
        $('#login_submit').on('click', function() {
            if(!$('#login_submit').hasClass('disabled')) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: url + 'login/ajaxLogin',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('#login_form').serialize(),
                    success: function(result) {
                        alert(result);
                        $("#login_submit").removeClass("m-progress disabled");
                    }
                });

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
class Login extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        //if($this->model->isUserLoggedIn()) 
            //header('Location: ' . URL . 'me');

        $news = $this->model->latestNews();

        require APP . 'view/_templates/header.php';
        require APP . 'view/login/index.php';
        require APP . 'view/_templates/footer.php';
    }

    /**
     * AJAX-ACTION: AjaxLogin
     * TODO documentation
     */
    public function ajaxLogin() {
        $errors = $this->model->doLoginWithPostData($_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_password']);
        echo $errors;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function doLoginWithPostData($user_email, $user_password) {
    if(empty($user_email) AND empty($user_password)) {
        return MESSAGE_ALL_EMPTY;
    } else if(empty($user_email)) {
        return MESSAGE_USERNAME_EMPTY;
    } else if(empty($user_password)) {
        return MESSAGE_PASSWORD_EMPTY;
    } else {
        $result_row = $this->getUserData(trim($user_email));

        if(!isset($result_row->id)) {
            return MESSAGE_USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST;
        } else if(($result_row->user_failed_logins >= 3) && ($result_row->user_last_failed_login > (time() - 30))) {
            return MESSAGE_PASSWORD_WRONG_3_TIMES;
        } else if(!password_verify($user_password, $result_row->password)) {
            $sth = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE users '
                    . 'SET user_failed_logins = user_failed_logins+1, user_last_failed_login = :user_last_failed_login '
                    . 'WHERE mail = :user_email');
            $sth->execute(array(':user_email' => $user_email, ':user_last_failed_login' => time()));

            return MESSAGE_PASSWORD_WRONG;
        } else {
            // write user data into PHP SESSION [a file on your server]
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result_row->id;
            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->username;
            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->mail;
            $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = 1;

            // reset the failed login counter for that user and set last ip and time
            $query = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE users '
                    . 'SET user_failed_logins = 0, user_last_failed_login = NULL, last_online = :time, ip_last = :ip '
                    . 'WHERE id = :user_id AND user_failed_logins != 0');
            $query->execute(array(':time' => time(), ':ip' => $this->getUserIP(), ':user_id' => $result_row->id));

            if(defined('HASH_COST_FACTOR')) {
                if(password_needs_rehash($result_row->password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array('cost' => HASH_COST_FACTOR))) {
                    $user_password_hash = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array('cost' => HASH_COST_FACTOR));

                    $query = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE users SET password = :user_password_hash WHERE id = :user_id');
                    $query->bindValue(':user_password_hash', $user_password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindValue(':user_id', $result_row->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $query->execute();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Está usando qual framework? CakePHP?

Comment: Nenhuma, é minha própria framework.

Answer (score 3):

A única coisa que eu iria recomendar é usando algum tipo de *nonce*.

Um nonce é um número que é utilizado apenas uma vez (por exemplo, um GUID). Quando a página é criada, também crie-se um *nonce* com uma certa chave. Quando faz-se o POST para o servidor, passa o *nonce* junto (tanto no *Header* ou no conteúdo/*body*). No lado do servidor, verifique se esse *nonce* existe na sessão, e se for certo, aceitar o login.

### Por que o nonce?

O propósito do *nonce* em aplicativos de Web, é para confirmar que o POST está sendo feito de origem confiável - nesse caso, a sua página, que é o único lugar que tem o lógico de criar o *nonce*, pois usa o mesmo algoritmo que o servidor usa para verificá-lo. Assim, não posso mandar um POST para essa página e tentar logar no seu site por meio de outro.

### Além Disso

Vejo que está usando várias práticas boas, incluíndo *paramaterization* das suas consultas ao banco de dados.

Comment: Infelizmente não tem um versão em português, mas [esse artigo do Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) explica um pouco mais.